Peek data at different stages of a Java stream (or compose functions)
Let say, I have the following elements:
class A {
    String s;

    String getS() {return s;}

    static boolean aFilter(String in) {return true or false}

    static A aTransformation(A a) {return another A}
}

I would like to do the following with Java stream:
List<A> myAs = provideTheList();

myAs.stream()
    .map(A::getS)
    .filter(A::aFilter)
    .map("back to stream of A")
    .map(A::aTransformation)
    .toList();

I know I can do it this way:
myAs.stream()
    .filter(a -> A.aFilter(a.getS()))
    .map(A::aTransformation)
    .toList();

But it breaks, the expression of code as a series of transformations. I want to avoid the "a -> ...". I could write a function to do the "A.aFilter(a.getS())", but the above pattern is quite common and it's cumbersome to write additional function just for this. Something like:
myAs.stream()
    .filter(A::aFilter ° A::getS) // function composition
    ...

would be perfect, but I don't know if we can express function composition in Java.
In Java we have predicates which are composable with and, or.
I do not found a way to compose functions in stream.
Another way would be to do the "back to stream of A", I do not believe it is possible to retrieve data at "another point of the stream".
Have you an elegant way to do the operation described above ?

why not change static boolean aFilter(...) to boolean aFilter() (non static, no parameter) or implement such a a method with different name (a bit more OO-like and functional than using static anyway) - no there is no need to map to String and back (sure can also be a static method, but accepting the instance of A instead of String)

Why not change... ? Because my point is how to pick data at different points in the stream and build construction with existing code and minimal changes. I use the keyword static in my exemple to say that the filter or transformation is rather independant from the rest of the code, it is just there for reuse.

You can create it yourself
static <T, U> Predicate<T> combine(Function<T, U> f, Predicate<U> p) {
    return (T t) -> p.test(f.apply(t));
}

And use it as
Stream.of(X.builder().build())
    .filter(combine(X::getS, String::isBlank))
    .toList();

PS: You can do stuff like this
Stream.of(X.builder().build())
    .filter(predicate(
        For.<X>type()
            .f(X::getS)
            .andThen(Object::toString)
            .andThen(String::isBlank)))
    .toList();

If you put little more effort in utilities you creating.
Here is code:
public class For<U> {
    private static For INSTANCE = new For();

    public static <U> For<U> type() { return INSTANCE; }

    public static <T> Predicate<T> predicate(Function<T, Boolean> f) {
        return f::apply;
    }

    public <R> Function<U, R> f(Function<U, R> f) { return f; }
}


EDIT
If you restricted by using pure JDK try this:
Stream.of(
        X.builder().build()
).filter(Function
        .<X>identity()
        .andThen(X::getS)
        .andThen(Object::toString)
        .andThen(String::isBlank)
        ::apply
).toList();


Thank you, I like your second answer which is quite elegant, but it is not what I am looking for. I search something more reusable out of the box (as JDK only as possible). Cause when you work on an existing project, your "For" class is something you will add in some utility package and it has to be accepted by the rest of the team.
I was looking for something very lightweight and without any additions.
But thanks for your idea which could be great in other cases.

@Jean-LucDelarbre Unfortunately Predicate is overlooked in standard library. Most of project I worked on use some sort of utility library like apache-common. You can look in those libraries you already using.

@Jean-LucDelarbre added one more option. I'm not proud of it, but it will do the job.

Add a method to A:
public boolean passes() {
    return aFilter(getS());
}

Then
myAs.stream()
    .map(A::passes)
    .map(A::aTransformation)
    .toList();

